# Parse through the JSON object in Angular

Tags: json, angular

I have a sample JSON named `SampleJSON` as below:

```
"type1":{
"0":{"title":"Title1","url":"URL1"},
"1":{"title":"Title2","url":"URL2"},
"2":{"title":"Title3","url":"U",
    "0":{"title":"Title1","url":"URL1"},
    "1":{"title":"Title2","url":"URL2"},
    -----------------------------------,
    -----------------------------------
}
"3":{"title":"Title4","url":"URL4"},
-----------------------------------,
-----------------------------------
}
```

How can i loop through the node `"type1"` in Angular5 and get the value for `title` & `url`.
I am stuck and cant move further after trying `ngFor`.

Comment: you want to iterate in HTML side of .ts side? Also your data is disordered as you can see in `type2` there is 0,1,2,3 but in `type1` there is not. Please post your full data here https://justpaste.it/

Comment: i need to iterate in HTML side.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/ Paste your whole JSON here and update the link

Comment: I have updated the Sample JSON in question.

Comment: again this is not valid format, you need to update at least valid format

Comment: i am getting this format of JSON from other team, do i need to make it array format like<br/>"type1":[{
"0":[{"title":"Title1","url":"URL1"}],
"1":[{"title":"Title2","url":"URL2"}],

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/170283/discussion-between-pardeep-jain-and-sdlbeginner).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just loop via keys

try this:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-y1wlkt?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent {
    name = 'Angular 5';

    test: any;
    testFinal: any[];

    constructor() {
      this.testFinal = [];
        this.test = {
            "type1": {
                "0": { "title": "Title1", "url": "URL1" },
                "1": { "title": "Title2", "url": "URL2" },
                "2": {
                    "title": "Title3", "url": "U",
                    "0": { "title": "Title1", "url": "URL1" },
                    "1": { "title": "Title2", "url": "URL2" },
                },
                "3": { "title": "Title4", "url": "URL4" }
            }
        }

        //Iterate the keys
        for(let x in this.test){

          for(let y in this.test[x]){
             this.testFinal.push(this.test[x][y]);
          }
        }
        console.log(this.testFinal)


    }
}
```

Comment: @John Velasquez, thank you for the direction. It helped us a lot.